# How to connect two variables when storing it to localStorage?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm writing my first app on Ionic. It's a simple notes app. I'm saving my list of notes like this:

```
save() {
    if(this.todoItem != "" && this.todoText != "") {
        this.todoList.push(this.todoItem);
        localStorage.setItem("todol", JSON.stringify(this.todoList));
        this.nav.pop();
    }
}
```

I want todoItem and todoText to be connected so when I push it to local storage JSON would look something like this:

```
{"todoList":[
    {"todoItem":"item1", "todoText":"text1"},
    {"todoItem":"item2", "todoText":"text2"},
    {"todoItem":"item3", "todoText":"text3"}
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing plain todoItem to the list, you can try forming an Object with the pattern you require as shown.

```
    save() {
    if(this.todoItem != "" && this.todoText != "") {

        this.todoList.push({"todoItem":this.todoItem , "todoText":this.todoText});
        localStorage.setItem("todol", JSON.stringify(this.todoList));
        this.nav.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I ignore this error: `Argument of type '{ "todoItem": string; "todoText": string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' `?

Comment: Maybe this? 
    `this.todoList.push({"todoItem":this.todoItem , "todoText":this.todoText}:any);`

Comment: @sneeky now `',' expected.`

Comment: hmmm, then it doesn't work ;)
Maybe this? `this.todoList.push({ todoItem: this.todoItem, todoText: this.todoText });`. No use of quotes at the keys? I am just guessing, I did not test it myself

Comment: @sneeky Nope, I get the same `Argument of type '{ todoItem: string; todoText: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` error. Maybe it has something to do with this file being TypeScript, not Javascript?

Comment: @DiamCho While declaring the type of ArrayList **todoList**  , make the type **any** instead of **string**. The other way would be to create an interface with two fileds **todoItem** , **todoText** and change the type of Arraylist to the **interface** instead of **any**. If you could post the snippet of code where you are declaring the Arraylist, we can provide much better solutions.

Comment: @DaimCho If the answer provided was useful, please upvote it :)

Comment: @siva967 I don't have enough reputation to upvote :(